# merge xml files using tinyxml2 in C++

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml2

Now I'm using tinyxml2 library for merge several xml files.
I want to checking xml files in same folder(I will use absolute path).
And when I combine several xml files, I will remove the duplicates and merge them by comparing the values of Firstchild Element and its first attribute.

I tried many cases, but not sure about which  can be merged in an accurate and fast way.
Now I will show what I want to get.

- First xml file

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
  <osm version="0.6" generator="    ">
    <node id="147782" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147788" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147794" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147829" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147835" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147843" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147850" visible="true" version="1" />
    <way id="10808" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="147788" />
      <nd ref="150133" />
      <nd ref="150145" /> 
    </way>
    <way id="10824" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="156232" />
      <nd ref="156240" />
      <nd ref="156251" />
    </way>
  ```
- Second xml file

  ```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <osm version="0.6" generator="    ">
    <node id="147843" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147850" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="438198" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="438199" visible="true" version="1" />
    <way id="10808" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="147788" />
      <nd ref="150133" />
      <nd ref="150145" />
    </way>
    <way id="10821" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="153211" />
      <nd ref="153230" />
      <nd ref="153243" />
    </way>
  ```
- Merged xml file

  ```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <osm version="0.6" generator="    "> 
    <node id="147782" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147788" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147794" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147829" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147835" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147843" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="147850" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="438198" visible="true" version="1" />
    <node id="438199" visible="true" version="1" />
    <way id="10808" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="147788" />
      <nd ref="150133" />
      <nd ref="150145" />
    </way>
    <way id="10824" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="156232" />
      <nd ref="156240" />
      <nd ref="156251" />
    </way>
    <way id="10821" visible="true" version="1">
      <nd ref="153211" />
      <nd ref="153230" />
      <nd ref="153243" /> 
    </way>
  ```

Like that Merged xml file, I want merge them without overlapping. In those case, it can be compare with node id and way id.

I'm sorry if my question sounded ambiguous. If there is something wrong, I will correct it as soon as possible.

Comment: Please share your attempt to fix the problem. We help people who try hard and fail, not people who simply ask. You got to sweat before you ask.

Comment: Am I mistaken or do those `XML` files require a root element?

Comment: @Galik In those case, I just scan root element's first attribute(id). I forgot first root element. <osm version="0.6" generator="  ">  
Now I tried to success get those attribute, but node root and way root are the same level so it is impossible to distinguish between the two.

for(tinyxml2::XMLElement* child1 =
    doc.FirstChildElement("osm")->FirstChildElement("node"); 
    child1 != 0; child1 = child1->NextSiblingElement()){

      if(child1->ToElement()->Attribute("id"))
          std::cout << "id = "   << child1->ToElement()->Attribute("id") << std::endl;}

Comment: Mayb try something like: `doc.RootElement()->FirstChildElement("node");`. Also edit the question to correct the `XML` files to have a root element.

Comment: @Galik Ok, I will try that case which you recommend to me. Thank you :)

Comment: @Galik I resolved thta problem! I thought root element was not important, but it wasn't. It was the starting point for me to distinguish in the way I wanted. Thank you and have a nice day!